# magento 2 Shipping modules does not update rate on zip code changes

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, custom-shipping-method

I got the issue.
When i am enabling default shipping module with my custom shipping module, it is refreshing the shipping section.
But when i am enabling only my custom shipping code, it is not getting refreshed when i am changing pincode.

Is there any update for this issues.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311199/magento-2-shipping-rates-only-refresh-on-address-change-when-a-standard-method-i). Not yet found a proper work around but enabling one of the standard methods (eg free shipping) and setting the minimum spend to something huge so it doesn't show does get the rates refreshing even when the built in rate isn't triggered